# How to add a Google Maps layer to Openscales?

Tags: flex, openscales

I'm using Openscales in a web mapping project. I would like to add a Google Maps layer, but I haven't found any snippets or examples. Any solution will be very helpful.

Comment: See code in this post http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21546/googlemaps-layer-on-openscales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/openscales-dev/browse_thread/thread/37a0c29374b374c6/bedf3fb6f75bda6b?pli=1) on the forum suggests that there is (or was in 2010) no support for Google Maps in OpenScales due to incompatible licenses.