# Google Maps layer on OpenScales

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, openscales

I'm using OpenScales in a web mapping project, and I would like to add a Google Maps layer. I know that there's some licence problems, but I don't care for these licence issues, I'm looking to add Google Maps layer to OpenScales like it has been made on OpenLayers.

Comment: you can use wms service like - http://peterdamen.com/GoogleWMS/googlewms.php.txt but your ip can be blocked by google if it is they deem it not an acceptable method in using their mapping tiles

Comment: Thanks a lot Mapperz, i will give a try for this solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create your own TMS layer and server side proxy script with crossdomain.xml

package openscalesmap
{

```
import org.openscales.core.layer.TMS;
import org.openscales.geometry.basetypes.Bounds;
import org.openscales.geometry.basetypes.Location;
import org.openscales.proj4as.ProjProjection;
import flash.system.Security;

public class GoogleMap extends TMS
{
    private var _serviceVersion:String = "1.0.0";       
    private var _tileOrigin:Location = null;        
    private var _format:String = "png";     
    private var _layerName:String;
    private var _type:String;
    private var _proxy_url:String="http://proxysite.com/swf/proxy.php?url=";

    public static const HYBRID:String="mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=h@159000000&hl=ru";
    public static const SAT:String="khm0.google.ru/kh/v=90";
    public static const STANDART:String="mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@159000000&hl=ru";

    public function GoogleMap(name:String, url:String, layerName:String="", type:String=SAT)
    {
        super(name, url, layerName);
        //flash.system.Security.allowDomain("mt0.google.com");
    /*  Security.loadPolicyFile("http://google.com/crossdomain.xml");
        Security.allowDomain( "*" );
        Security.allowInsecureDomain( "*" );*/
        this.projection = new ProjProjection("EPSG:900913");
        this._layerName = layerName;
        _type=type;
        this.maxExtent = new Bounds(-20037508.34,-20037508.34,20037508.34,20037508.34);
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    override public function getURL(bounds:Bounds):String {
        var res:Number = this.map.resolution;
        if(this._tileOrigin==null) {
            this._tileOrigin = new Location(this.maxExtent.left,this.maxExtent.bottom);
        }

        var x:Number = Math.round((bounds.left - this.maxExtent.left) / (res * this.tileWidth));
        var y:Number = Math.round((this.maxExtent.top - bounds.top) / (res * this.tileHeight));
        var z:Number = this.map.zoom;
        var limit:Number = Math.pow(2, z);


        x = ((x % limit) + limit) % limit;
        y = ((y % limit) + limit) % limit;
        var url:String =_proxy_url+escape(_type + "&z=" + z + "&x=" + x + "&y=" + y); 

        if (this.altUrls != null) {
            url = this.selectUrl(this.url, this.getUrls());
        }

        return url ;
    }
}
```

}

And change these lines for your language:

```
public static const HYBRID:String="mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=h@159000000&hl=ru";
public static const SAT:String="khm0.google.ru/kh/v=90";
public static const STANDART:String="mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@159000000&hl=ru";
```